# Ubuntu Software icon missing!

Tags: 20.04, software-center, icons

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my old 2008 macbook, and I noticed that there is no icon for the Ubuntu software center.  Instead there's a diamond with gears on it.  Is this fixable?  Is it because of my computer's age?  Please help.

Comment: What is the icon theme you are using?

Comment: Applications - Yaru Light. Icons - Humanity

Comment: Try not using humanity theme and using Yaru

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but prefer the Humanity theme over the Yaru one. (I first changed the theme to preview the Yaru theme via **Gnome Tweaks**)

My solution was as follows:

- go to **Dash**
- open a **Menu Editor** (if necessary install a **Menu Editor**, such as **MenuLibre**)
- find **Ubuntu Software** (**System Tools** --> **Ubuntu Software**)
- left click icon (I had a blank icon showing)
- **Browse Files...**
- browse to the Yaru folder and select your desired size of the following icon: **ubuntusoftware.png** (stored under /usr/share/icons)